# JQuery events mouseenter mousemove behaviour in IE

Tags: jquery, events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#outer').mouseenter(function(){
    console.log("mouse enter");
  });
  $('#outer').mousemove(function(){
    console.log("mouse move");
  });
});
```

```
<div style='width:800px;border:1px  solid red' id="outer">
 this is test
</div>
```

when mouse entered the div In firefox,chrome mouseenter event is getting fired first than mouse move in case of IE mousemove event getting fired first than mouseenter. Is this know bug ? or is there any other way so that all browsers can behave in same way

Answer (score 8):

**[Updated Answer]**

There are two ways to get around this.

1) only bind your `mousemove` event on the `mousenter` event so all subsequent events would properly fire in the same order. *This involves a lot of binding and unbinding.*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var outer_mousemove = function(){ console.log('mousemove') };

    $("#outer").hover(function(){
       console.log('mouseenter');
       // Attach the event listener only after
       // Mouse enter has fired
       $(this).mousemove( outer_mousemove );
    }, function(){
       $(this).unbind('mousemove', outer_mousemove );
    });
});
```

2) Store a variable, and only execute mousemove events when the conditions match. Much less binding/unbinding this way (This is how I would do it if it were my project):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var outer_mousemove = false;

    $("#outer").hover(function(){
       console.log('mouseenter');
       outer_mousemove = true;
    }, function(){
       console.log('mouseleave');
       outer_mousemove = false;
    }).mousemove(function(){
       if( outer_mousemove ){
         console.log('mousemove');
       }
    });
});
```

**[Original Answer]**

`mouseenter` is a special event created by jQuery which is why it might fire after `mousemove`. What you probably want is `mouseover`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#outer').mouseover(function(){
    console.log("mouse over");
  }).mousemove(function(){
    console.log("mouse move");
  });
});
```

Additionally, to keep from receiving multiple mouseover events from child elements, you could test to make sure you are only acting on events generated by your object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#outer').mouseover(function(e){
    if(e.target == this){
      console.log("mouse over");
    }
  }).mousemove(function(){
    console.log("mouse move");
  });
});
```

Finally, in my answer I used chaining (i.e. 'mouseover().mousemove()') instead of calling the selector `$("#outer")` twice. This just makes your page a little faster :)

Comment: sorry to say, but in your case too, in FF mouseover triggers before mousemove, whereas in IE mousemove triggers before mouseover. http://jsbin.com/oxigi/7

Comment: @Rakesh Juyal, Thanks for testing. I updated my answer to handle the tests to guarantee action only after initial `mouseenter`.