# Mouse leave on drop down is not working IE

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

The below html code results in a red colored div and within it, there is a select element. With the div, attached a mouseenter and mouseleave events i.e. when mouse pointer is hovered on the div, the div background color turns yellow and when leaving out of div, it turns back to red again.

In mozilla, when mouse pointer is entered into the div, it turns yellow. when I select the dropdown option values, then also it remains yellow but this is not happening in IE. When I select even the first option, the div background turns red which should not happen. Please help me out with this example.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#selectDiv").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#selectDiv").css("background-color","yellow");
}).mouseleave(function(){
        $("#selectDiv").css("background-color","red");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="selectDiv" style="margin:20px; background-color:red;height:100px;width:100px;">
<select style="margin:10px;">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which version of IE the behaviour is broken?

Comment: I think something similar is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278514/jquery-events-mouseenter-mousemove-behaviour-in-ie

Comment: created a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/3GhT2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064011/482063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AngelWorkz nice work. The select box is a bit tricky in most versions of ie. Clicking on it would correctly (given the way it renders select boxes) trigger a mouseleave / mouseout.

My advice is to use a timer.. do something like

http://jsfiddle.net/3GhT2/1/

```
$(function(){

  var graceTimer = null;

  $("#selectDiv").mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(graceTimer);
        $("#selectDiv").css("background-color","yellow");
    }).mouseout(function(){
      graceTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#selectDiv").css("background-color","red");
      }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think it is great pleasure to have your code here, i used this code in my project, it is working good, Thanks SkippyChalmers.